# A more efficient way to pick and place tiles?

Tags: actionscript-3

is it wrong to pick and place my tiles like this?
In other words, whats a better way to place the tiles so removing and adding a different tile is easy. Or what is a good method of doing so with the way i have it set up. 
Whats a good way to reference a specific tile on the map?

```
public class Stage extends MovieClip
{

    protected var tilesInWorld:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>();
    public var worldTiles:Sprite;
    protected var tile:MovieClip;

    protected var TILE_SIZE:int = 5;
    protected var map_width:int = 800;
    protected var map_height:int = 600;
    protected var pmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(map_width,map_height);
    protected var _seed:uint = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    protected var grid_width:uint = new uint(map_width / TILE_SIZE);
    protected var grid_height:uint = new uint(map_height / TILE_SIZE);
    protected var heightmap:Array = new Array();
    protected var pixelPoint:Point = new Point();
    protected var darkest_pixel:Number = 1;
    protected var brightest_pixel:Number = 0;
    protected var hm :Number;


    public function Stage()
    {
        pmap.perlinNoise(map_width,map_height, 6, _seed, true, false, 1, true);
        for (var i:uint=0; i < grid_width; i++)
        {
            heightmap[i] = new Array();
            for (var j:uint=0; j < grid_height; j++)
            {
                heightmap[i][j] = new uint();
            }
        }
        //Divide the map in to a 7x7 grid and take data at each interval
        for (i=0; i < grid_width; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j < grid_height; j++)
            {
                pixelPoint.x = Math.round((i/grid_width) * pmap.width)+1;
                pixelPoint.y = Math.round((j/grid_width) * pmap.height)+1;
                heightmap[i][j] = pmap.getPixel(pixelPoint.x,pixelPoint.y);
                heightmap[i][j] /=  0xffffff;

                if (heightmap[i][j] < darkest_pixel)
                {
                    darkest_pixel = heightmap[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        //Adjust values to a min of 0
        for (i=0; i < grid_width; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j < grid_height; j++)
            {
                heightmap[i][j] -=  darkest_pixel;

                if (heightmap[i][j] > brightest_pixel)
                {
                    brightest_pixel = heightmap[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        //Adjust values to highest value of 1
        for (i=0; i < grid_width; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j < grid_height; j++)
            {
                heightmap[i][j] /=  brightest_pixel;
            }
        }
        worldTiles = new Sprite();
        addChild(worldTiles);
        placeTile();
    }
```

The part below this is the main part im referring too

```
    protected function placeTile()
    {
        for (var i=0; i < grid_width; i++)
        {
            for (var j=0; j < grid_height; j++)
            {
                hm = heightmap[i][j]; 
                if (hm >= 0.84)
                {
                    tile = new Water();
                }
                else if (hm >= 0.8 && hm < 0.84)
                {
                    tile = new Shallow();
                }
                else if (hm >= 0.7 && hm < 0.8)
                {
                    tile = new Sand();
                }
                else if (hm >= 0.2 && hm < 0.7)
                {
                    tile = new Tile();
                }
                else
                {
                    tile = new Stone();
                }
                tile.width = TILE_SIZE;
                tile.height = TILE_SIZE;
                worldTiles.x = 0;
                worldTiles.y = 0;
                tile.x = TILE_SIZE * (i % grid_width);
                tile.y = TILE_SIZE * (j % grid_height);
                tilesInWorld.push(tile);
                worldTiles.addChild(tile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is there a more efficient way of picking and placing the tiles?
and while i have your attention, how can i go about deleting and replacing the tiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to not do so many array look-ups.

```
 //..
 var hm :Number;
 for (var i=0; i < grid_width; i++)
 {
    for (var j=0; j < grid_height; j++)
    {
        hm = heightmap[i][j]; 

        if (hm >= 0.84)
        {
            tile = new Water();
        }
        else if ( hm >= 0.8 && hm < 0.84)
        {
             //...
```

Also you might want to look at object pooling. [Here is a nice video tutorial about object pooling.](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=160)

Apart of that I can't see much more to optimise here. But I am sure others will give you more tips.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I made edits implementing the 'hm' suggestion. And will be looking into replacing my code with object pooling.

Comment: lol well it didnt help me to the point where i think this question was answered soooo